# Need help to extract data from Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hello I have this data:

```
var data={
"city_id": "2",
"dist": "2",
"City Name 1": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "name 1",
"address": "address 1",
"tel": "tel 1",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "name 2",
"address": "address 2",
"tel": "tel 2",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
}
],{
"city_id": "2",
"dist": "2",    
"City Name 2": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "name 1",
"address": "address 1",
"tel": "tel 1",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "name 2",
"address": "address 2",
"tel": "tel 2",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
}
]
}
};
```

I want to loop through this JSON data to extract City_id, dist_id, City Name, and then another loop to get name and address and telephone. The data format is not correct, I don't know how to fix it.

I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: at first) this is not valid json but js object. You can use "for" function with "in". http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: What will be the output, an array?

Comment: @BerozaPaul No, I want to display the data in a table

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are off making this not a valid json.

```
var data={ //------------------------------------open
"city_id": "2",
"dist": "2",
 "City Name 1": [
{//----------------------open
"id": 1,
"name": "name 1",
"address": "address 1",
"tel": "tel 1",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
},//----------------------close
{//-----------------------open
"id": 2,
"name": "name 2",
"address": "address 2",
"tel": "tel 2",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
}//----------------------close
],{//----------------------------------open (problem is here. There is nothing index this object}
"city_id": "2",
"dist": "2",    
"City Name 2": [
{//-----------------------open
"id": 1,
"name": "name 1",
"address": "address 1",
"tel": "tel 1",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
},//----------------------close
{//-----------------------open
"id": 2,
"name": "name 2",
"address": "address 2",
"tel": "tel 2",
"Radio": "0",
"surgery": "0"
}//----------------------close
]
}//----------------------------------close
}; //------------------------------------------------close
```

That bit needs to be in the array or removed from the json.

Comment: I could not fix it. Is there a way to do it !